# The image is not changing on change event Vue

Tags: http, vuejs3

I have an input type file, every time I change an image, new image should appear, but that new image is not changing, it sticks to old one. Only when I update the page the new image is selected

I tried to update the image, but still it sticks to old one.

template:  `

```
                      <input
                        class="file-upload"
                        type="file"
                        accept="image/*"
                        @change="uploadCompanyLogo"
                      />
```

`

` async uploadCompanyLogo(event) {
const file = event.target.files[0];
const extension = file.name.split(".").pop();

```
  const fileReader = new FileReader();
  fileReader.onload = async (event) => {
    const base64 = event.target.result.toString();

    let requestBody = {
      token: this.token,
      imageData: base64,
      extension: extension,
    };
    console.log("base64", base64);
    try {
      const response = await this.$http.post(
        "some endpoint to post",
        requestBody,
        {
          headers: {
            "Content-Type": "application/json",
          },
        }
      );

      if (response.status === 200) {
        const logoUrl = await response.data;
        this.companyLogo = logoUrl;
```

}
fileReader.readAsDataURL(file);`

The base64 variable is changing, but companyLogo still remains the same, maybe